# Jquery firing off when text field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/PUVkw/4/

I have a text field I am attempting to use some javascript to do some front end validation. Im using jquery mobile and trying to attach an event to the textfield but these event seems to fire on page load.

```
 $("#FirstName").bind ("change", namecheck('FirstName','K'));
 $("#FirstName").bind ("blur", namecheck('FirstName','B'));
```

I have tried various things for change and blur... ie OnBlur, Blur.... The name check function always runs on page load

I would like to use onkeyup and onblur but no luck yet...

Thanks,
JT

Comment: Pay better attention to the syntax....Its a little different then JavaScript :) happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding a function. You are now trying to bind the result of the function call `namecheck('FirstName','K')` as a function. Try something like this:

```
$("#FirstName").bind ("change", function(){namecheck('FirstName','K');});
$("#FirstName").bind ("blur", function(){namecheck('FirstName','B');});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it this way -

```
$("#FirstName").bind ("change", function(){ // callback function
   namecheck('FirstName','K');
});

$("#FirstName").bind ("blur", function(){  // callback function
   namecheck('FirstName','B');
});
```

The way you are doing is wrong as when you write this `namecheck('FirstName','K')` you are actually invoking the function which makes it to run on page load.